# The resource cannot be found in asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created an ASP.NET webforms application and it runs successfully, but after few when I open my project and run in VS then my project shows the error shown here. I searched about the error but I can't get exact solution.

The main problem not in path or link the main issues on my system because when I run application, I get the same issue, but then I off my antivirus, then it's working.

But now if I off the antiviruses then I will not working it's showing me the same problem.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBeqz.png)

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Login.aspx

Version information:

Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0

Comment: can you show a code how you open login page ? using Response.Redirect or through link button src?

Comment: I set on Config File first open login page 
         <files>  
            <add value="Login.aspx" />  
         </files>  
Like This.

Comment: use ~ in front of Login ~/Login.aspx like this